# Чи правильно вживати словосполучення "підзорна труба"?

Tags: росіянізм, словосполучення

Виникло запитання чи **підзорна труба**  є питомо українським словосполученням чи наявні російські впливи. У [ВІкіпедії](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%96%D0%B4%D0%B7%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B0_%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B1%D0%B0) знаходимо статтю з синонімами до цієї назви, які, на мою думку, звучать набагато краще:

> **Зорова (далекоглядна)** труба́.

Статтю з даним виразом маємо у і в [СУМі](http://sum.in.ua/s/pidzornyj).

Однак, [доктор філологічних наук О. Пономарів](http://svoboda-news.com/svwp/%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B2%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BC%D0%BE-%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%97%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D1%83-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%83-9/) вважає:

> У словниках є **підзорна труба**, але цього росіянізму краще не вживати. Українською мовою – **далекоглядна труба**.

Отже, чи правильно вживати **далекоглядна труба?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Зазвичай "далекогляд" вживають як [синонім](http://hrinchenko.com/slovar/znachenie-slova/11390-dalekoghljad.html) до слова "телескоп", а "[телескоп](http://sum.in.ua/s/teleskop)" та "підзорна труба" - це різні речі. Також, якщо звернемося до сайту [Словотвір](https://slovotvir.org.ua/words/teleskop), то побачимо, що там до саме до слова "телескоп" відносять  відповідники "далекогляд" та "зорегляд".

Однак, варто зазначити, що на основі цього всього можна припустити, що можливо сказати "далекоглядна труба", в такому разі не виникне плутанини із телескопом, крім того, ви й самі навели приклад з Вікіпедії, де зазначається такий варіант.

Але щодо варіанту "підзорна труба" - він також є прийнятний, адже в українській мові є такі слова як "підзорний", "підзоряти" і "підзорити" (див. [джерело](https://dul.in.ua/pidzornyj)). Також, якщо ввести в СУМі слово "[труба](http://sum.in.ua/s/truba)", то бачимо: "Зорова (підзорна) труба див. зоровий, підзорний". Такщо, як бачите можемо зробити висновок, що можна сказати "підзорна труба", а також - "[зорова труба](http://sum.in.ua/s/zorovyj)" (однак, згідно до [Вікіпедії](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%97%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0_%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B1%D0%B0) тут не все так просто і цей термін включає в себе і підзорні труби, і телескопи, і біноклі, тощо).

Крім того, при перекладі російського "подзорная труба" на українську знаходимо в Українсько-російському політехнічному словнику варіант "підзорна труба".